# Why are there duplicate startup entries

Tags: boot

Autoruns shows many duplicate startup entries, as you see [image: in this screenshot]

Mostly these don't trouble me. But for example the pink highlighted one causes "Already running - do you want to replace?" messages for the dozen AutoHotkey scripts it executes - which gets tedious.

How do these arise and how can can I fix them please?

(They are both for 'All Users', so that eliminates one obvious cause.)

Comment: Have you do a search through the registry hive for these enteries?  If you disable one of the enteries, does the program still startup, if so just delete it after your test.

Comment: Q1: I'm working through the registry right now.
Q2: That was the first thing I tried. If I delete either entry, the program does not start!

Comment: How many users do you have on the system?

Comment: Just myself---!

Answer (score 0):

For AutoHotkey duplicates you can edit the scripts you're using and add `#SingleInstance, Force`,  `#SingleInstance, Ignore`, `#SingleInstance, Off`, etc., to tailor those dialogs on a re-launch.

See help for `#SingleInstance`.

This is the lazy workaround in this case to not have to weed through your registry entries, but it can also be used to fix the same thing happening in other cases as well, say you accidently run the script again manually (and don't want a dialog), or say you purposefully want to have the new instance replace the old instance.

Comment: Thanks, I will probably end up doing that. I had same advice in the AHK forum. But I hate unsolved puzzles and ideally would like to discover the underlying cause!